# Check All Values in Range1 Against All Values in Range 2 for Exact Match

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare all values in Range1 (cells in U:X of the active row), excluding blanks, against all values in Range2 (m, n), excluding blanks, and--if there's an exact match between the ranges--change the color of column Y in the active row, else do not change the color.

Example:

Range1 contains Dog, Cat, Bird, [blank cell], and Range2 includes Dog, Cat, Bird, [multiple blank cells] = MATCH

Range1 contains Dog, Cat, [blank cell], [blank cell] and Range2 includes Dog, Cat, Bird, [multiple blank cells] = NO MATCH

Here's what I have so far, but yColumn is not changing color when there's a complete match. Do I need another loop?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cVal As String
    Dim tRow, lRow As Long
    Dim pID As String
    Dim yColumn As Integer
    cVal = Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
    tRow = Target.Row
    yColumn = 25
    lRow = Sheet4.Range("A1200").End(xlUp).Row
    pID = Sheet1.Range("A" & tRow).Value
    
' Check for ALL Cells Match
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U2:X1500")) Is Nothing Then
            Sheet1.Cells(tRow, yColumn).Interior.Color = xlNone
                For m = 2 To lRow
                    If Sheet4.Range("A" & m).Value = pID Then
                For n = 11 To 28
                        If Sheet4.Cells(m, n).Value = cVal And Sheet4.Cells(m, n).Value <> "" And Target(Range("U2:X1500")) = Sheet4.Cells(m, n).Value Then
                        Sheet1.Cells(tRow, yColumn).Interior.Color = 914271
                        Exit Sub
                        End If
                Next n
                    End If
                Next m
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect from `cVal = Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value`? What do you expect from `Target(Range("U2:X1500")) = Sheet4.Cells(m, n).Value`?

Comment: Please, better describe the way of comparing that ranges. Are there more possible occurrences of `pID` in `Sheet4.Range("A" & m)`? What about Dog, Cat, Bird in `Range` and only Dog, Cat in the second one? What about no empty cells?

Comment: The event is a macro on `Sheet1`, though not in a module. Range1 is a  range of cells in columns U:X on the active row, and Range2 is a range of columns (K:AB) in Sheet4 that are returned from the row that includes the corresponding value based on cVal. That parts works ok. `cVal = Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value` defines the value that determines what two rows in Sheet1 and Sheet4 the ranges are being compared on. `Target(Range("U2:X1500")) = Sheet4.Cells(m, n).Value` is expected to match U:X of the target or active row against the values return from the m and n loops.

Comment: `pID` only occurs once in both Sheet1 and Sheet4 in column A. The macro takes the `pID` in column A of the active row in Sheet1 and searches for `pID` in column A of Sheet4. Once located, it starts to compare U:X of the active row in Sheet1 against (K:AB) of the located row in Sheet4 for matches. The expected results are, if all cells with values in Sheet1 match all cells with values in Sheet4, ignoring any blank cells, column Y of the active row in Sheet1 changes color, else nothing happens.

Comment: It cannot run in a sheet, an event runs in a sheet module. Since the event works for changes in `Sheet1`, `Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value` should be exactly `Target.Value`. Since `Target` is a range,  I still cannot understand what `Target(Range("U2:X1500"))` should return. Doesn't it return an error? Are you sure that your code reaches this line?

Comment: But what if **all cells with values in Sheet1 match all cells with values in Sheet4, but some more values (not blank) in Sheet4**?

Comment: Are there less than 1200 rows in `Sheet4` A:A? Do you need the last row of A:A, in fact?

Comment: That's a good point. If all cells with values in Sheet1 match all cells with values in Sheet4, but some more values (not blank) in Sheet4, then NO MATCH. Essentially, all values must match all values exactly. Any extra or missing values in either Sheet1 or Sheet4 is NO MATCH. I updated `Target(Range("U2:X1500"))` to `Target.Value` as you suggested, and column Y does change color if ANY match is found, but I only want it to change if ALL matches are found.

Comment: I did not suggest `Target.Value` instead of `Target(Range("U2:X1500"))`, which is a strange construction. I only tried stating that `Sheet1.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value` should be exactly `Target.Value`. Are you sure that didn't use `On Error Resume Nexgt` and VBA does not raise an error, even if it exists

Comment: Understood! At any rate, the change did get me a step closer than I was to the expected results. And there are exactly 1077 rows of data in `Sheet4` A:A. I do not need the last row, only using the extended range to keep from having to update the macro every time new data was added to `Sheet4`, but certainly can if that's one of the issues here.

Comment: I will prepare an answer in some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lRow As Long, pID As String, yColumn As Long, m As Long
    Dim arrUX, arrKAB, El1, El2, boolFound As Boolean
    yColumn = 25
    lRow = Sheet4.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    pID = Me.Range("A" & Target.row).Value
    
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U2:X1500")) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Interior.color = xlNone
            For m = 2 To Target.row
                If Sheet4.Range("A" & m).Value = pID Then
                    arrUX = Me.Range(Me.cells(Target.row, "U"), Me.cells(Target.row, "X")).Value
                    arrKAB = Sheet4.Range(arrKAB.cells(m, "K"), Sheet4.cells(m, "AB")).Value
                    For Each El1 In arrUX
                        boolFound = False
                        For Each El2 In arrKAB
                            If El1 <> "" Then
                                If El1 = El2 Then boolFound = True: Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        If Not boolFound Then Exit Sub 'if one element of the first array is not found, existing
                    Next El1
                    If boolFound Then
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                         Target.Interior.color = 914271
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        Exit Sub 'since only one occurrence should exist...
                    End If
                End If
            Next m
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Still testing this. Getting a "Next without For" error on `Next m`.

Comment: @katech725 Ups... I missed a `End If` after `Exit Sub`. Please, try the updated code. Anyhow, it checks only first range against the second. If it works, from this point of view, as you need, I can adapt it to do the reverse check, too.

Comment: This is great. I believe I can get this to work with what you've demonstrated, thank you for the updated script.

Comment: @katech725 You should only repeat the iterations starting with `arrKAB` and taking care at `boolFound` use.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim v, lr As Long, tRow As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    Dim pID As String, c As Range
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("U:X")) Is Nothing Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
    
    tRow = Target.Row
    For Each c In Sheet1.Range("U1:X1").Offset(tRow - 1)
        If Len(c) > 0 Then
            s1 = s1 & Trim(c) & "|"
        End If
    Next

    ' find on sheet 4
    pID = Sheet1.Range("A" & tRow).Value
    With Sheet4
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        v = Application.Match(pID, .Range("A1:A" & lr), 0)
        If IsError(v) Then Exit Sub
        
        For Each c In .Range("K1:AB1").Offset(v - 1)
            If Len(c) > 0 Then
                 s2 = s2 & Trim(c) & "|"
            End If
        Next
        
        If s1 = s2 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(tRow, 25).Interior.Color = 914271
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(tRow, 25).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
       
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not able to get this to work. I replaced the final `Interior.Color` lines with a simple `MsgBox` to see if perhaps some conditional formatting in the sheet was preventing the color changes with no luck. Will continue testing.